How to add multi-line message in IBM MQ?
I want to add multi-line message to my IBM, where it should not treat a new line as a new message, My messages are seperated by "}", Is there any other way to do so? The below is the option which I tried.
I tried amqsput
`/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsput IBP.GCRP.BTR.Q.Q.Q.PUT.AQ Q_Manager < msg.txt`

msg.txt has text which I want to put in MQ, But the problem is that it takes next lines as seperate message.
For Example the Message:
`1235
{hkjdhsfk:
:kjhhkj
:hjksdf
:hkf
-}`

Is taken as
`MSG1= 1235
MSG2= {hkjdhsfk:
MSG3= :kjhhkj
MSG4= :hjksdf
MSG5= :hkf
MSG6= -}`

I want (with the next line '/n'):
MSG1:
`1235
{hkjdhsfk:
:kjhhkj
:hjksdf
:hkf
-}
`


amqsput is just a sample program shipped with IBM MQ, You can alter the code in the amqsput sample to read multiple lines from stdin before putting them as a single message if you wish.

Maybe you should give RFHUtil a chance: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil

amqsput is just a sample program - you can see from its source code that it works on individual input lines. It should be easy for to modify the program to do something like read lines until you give it an empty one and only then MQPUT the assembled message.
There's no sample program shipped with the product that deals with multiple line input.

As others have pointed out, amqsput is a sample program supplied with MQ.
A long time ago, I wrote 2 simple programs that do a basic version of what you want: File2Msg and Msg2File. You can find them here. The download includes builds for Windows. If you want to use them on other platforms, you will need to compile & link them.
Now, if you want a GUI tool to manipulate messages on a queue then you should have a look at MQ Visual Edit. Note: MQ Visual Edit is a commercial product but there is a free trial release.

Thanks for your reply, Roger. can you please also with the error:   #include <cmqc.h>
fatal error: cmqc.h: No such file or directory
I tried to run using:

gcc -o file2msg -I/opt/mqm/inc file2msg.c -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -lmqm
gcc -m64 -o file2msg_64 file2msg.c -I
gcc -o file2msg file2msg.c


You need MQ to be installed on Linux. In particular, to compile and link an MQ application, you need rpm MQSeriesSDK to be installed.  To see what MQ rpms you have installed, issue the following command:  rpm -qa | grep MQ
